# Proving the existence of identity of the fundamental group of homotopy theory $ \pi ( X,p)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

My trial is : 
I guess that the identity is the constant loop, which I can denote it by $ C(t) = p$ for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

But I know that the path C is an identity iff $C.a = a$ and $b.C = b$ whenever $ C.a$ and $ b.C$ are defined. So my question is why we are taking in the first equality of the definition a path called a while in the second equality we are taking a different path called b?

Also, how to verify the existence of an identity element for the fundamental  group by the definition I mentioned above ?

Comment: What is C.a? Can you explain better?

Comment: @Marco Lecci  it is the product of 2 paths.

Comment: In general the product of two paths is not symmetric. If $X$ is not empty and $p$ is fixed then the identity  path exists because you can define it like you did.

Comment: It seems that you use the notation from Crowell and Fox's " Introducton to Knot Theory" as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283178. Is that corrrect?

Comment: Yes that is correct @Paul Frost

Comment: @Paul Frost   but my question is different.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to confirm the notational context.

Comment: If $P$ and $Q$ are sentences each with one free variable, the statement "(for all $a$, $P(a)$ is true) and (for all $b$, $Q(b)$ is true)" is equivalent to the statement "for all $a$, $P(a)$ is true and $Q(a)$ is true)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental group $\pi(X,p)$ does not consist of $p$-based loops, but of **equivalence classes** of such loops with respect to the relation $\simeq$ defined by fixed-endpoint family of paths. This is a sort of homotopy between paths (but in contrast to ordinary homotopy it also relates  paths with different stopping times).

The identity path $e_p$ at $p$ is a $p$-based loop and we know that for any $p$-based loop $a$ we have $e_p \cdot a = a$ and $a \cdot e_p = a$. This transfers to equivalence classes: We have $[e_p] \cdot [a] = [e_p \cdot a] = [a]$ and $[a] \cdot [e_p] = [a \cdot e_p] = [a]$. However, instead of $e_p$ you may also take any constant path $c$ at $p$ ($c : [0, \lVert c \rVert] \to X, c(t) = p$). This is true because $[e_p] = [c]$.

The benefit of working with equivalence classes is that $\pi(X,p)$ becomes a group. If we work on the loop level, then multiplication of loops leads to addition of stopping times and thus never produces an identity path unless both factors are identity paths.

Remark:

It should be mentioned that the approach by Crowell and Fox differs from that in most other books. Usually a path in a space $X$ is defined as a continuous map $a :[0,1] \to X$ defined on the unit interval $[0,1]$. In the sense of Crowell and Fox this is path with stopping time $1$. For the sake of distinction let us denote such a path as a *normal path* (it is just an ad hoc notation, you will not find it in the literature). This standard approach has disandvantages and advantages. The main disadavantage is that the product $a \cdot b$ of normal paths obtained by "putting $b$ after $a$" as Crowell and Fox do is a map defined on $[0,2]$ which is no longer a normal path. Thus you define $a * b$ (which is again an ad hoc notation to distguish it from $a \cdot b$) by
$$a * b =
\begin{cases}
a(2t) & t \le 1/2 \\
b(2t-1) & t \ge 1/2
\end{cases}
$$
which is a normal path. This operation is not associative and does not have identities. Thus Crowell and Fox's approach behaves better in that respect.

The advantage is that the equivalence of normed paths is defined simpler: For normed paths $a, b$ such that $a(0) = b(0) = p_0$ and $a(1) = b(1) = p_1$ we write $a \simeq_* b$ if there exists a homotopy $H : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $H(t,0) = a(t), H(t,1) = b(t)$ for all $t$ and $H(0,s) = p_0, H(1,s) = p_1$ for all $s$.

It is an easy exercise to show that for each path $a$ there exists a normed path $a_*$ (with the same initial point and the same terminal point as $a$) such that $a \simeq a_*$ and that for normed paths $a_*, b_*$ one has $a_* \simeq_* b_*$ iff $a_* \simeq b_*$. Thus on the level of equivalence classes both approaches produce the same result: We have a $1-1$-correspondence between equivalence classes of paths $[a]_\simeq$ and equivalence classes of normed paths $[a_*]_{\simeq_*}$.

Comment: And why a and b are different paths in the definition of the identity in the book ?

Comment: When defining the concept of an "identity path" $e$ the authors do not restrict to loops. For not necessarily closed paths $a, b$ the path $e \cdot a$ is only defined if $e(\lVert e \rVert) = a(0)$ and $b \cdot e$ is only defined if $e(0) = b(\lVert b \rVert)$. Thus, for a **fixed** $e$ at most one of $e \cdot a$ and $a \cdot e$ is defined if $a$ is not a loop.

Comment: so you are saying that we proof that the fundamental group is a group with respect to the operation $\simeq $ is a group not with the operation of the product of 2 loops ...... correct? and this is because the group is a group of equivalence classes not a group of paths .....correct? and this is why we want to prove that this operation is well-defined .... correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.The set of $p$-based loops is a monoid (= semigroup with two-sided identity). Except the identity loop no element has an inverse. If you take equivalence classes $[a]$ of loops $a$ with respect to $\simeq$, then it turns out that $[a] \cdot [b] := [a \cdot b]$ is well-defined so that the set $\pi(X,p)$ of these equivalence classes is again a monoid - but in this set **each** element has an inverse.