# The difference between proving the existence of the inverse of the fundamental group between a book and a youtube lecture.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, alternative-proof, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

The following lecture proof the existence of the inverse for the fundamental group starting from minuite 15:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVxPwbUCep0&list=PLCgncMh0TrClLOU991FDEQK5LF_Aqm4FS&index=5

But "Introduction to knot theory book" of Richard H. Crowell, prove it as follows:

> [image]
>
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

But I want to transform the homotopy given in the book to what given on youtube, because what is given in the book is not clear for me, could anyone help me in doing so please?

Comment: I think you do not expect that anybody takes the time (19:35) to watch the youtube video. Can you explain what precisely is not clear to you in the book?

Comment: why $0 \leq t  \leq s ||a||$? why the stopping time is multiplied by $s$ @PaulFrost?

Comment: Note that the notations $t$ and $s$ are interchanged in the lecture (compared to the book). Both parameterizations look very similar - a little bit along the path and then back to the original point. How far along the path depends on the other (homotopy) parameter (which is also very natural thing to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend to read my answer to [Proving the existence of identity of the fundamental group of homotopy theory $ \pi ( X,p)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284048) where you can see the difference between the approach by Crowell and Fox and the "standard" approach to the fundamental group. Both approaches are equivalent (i.e. result in the same fundamental group) but are *technically* different.

For your question observe that identity paths in the sense of Crowell and Fox have stopping time $0$. In the "standard" approach all paths have stopping time $1$, thus on the level of individual paths you do not have identity elements. However, if you work on the level of equivalence classes of paths, then you easily see that the equivalence class of the constant path at a point $p$ is an identity.

Crowell and Fox prove that $a \cdot a^{-1} \simeq e_1$ and $a^{-1} \cdot a \simeq e_2$. To this end they construct a fixed-endpoint family of paths $h_s$ between $e_1$ and $a \cdot a^{-1}$ (the other case is treated similarly). The stopping $\lVert h_s \rVert$ time of $h_s$ must vary from $0$ for $s= 0$ and $2\lVert a \rVert$ for $s = 1$. This is most easily done by setting $\lVert h_s \rVert = 2s \lVert a \rVert$. The definition of $h_s$ is now fairly obvious (see Figure 12 in the book): For $t \in [0,s \lVert a \rVert]$ go "ascending" with $a$ from $a(0)$ to $a(s \lVert a \rVert)$, for $t \in [s \lVert a \rVert, 2s \lVert a \rVert]$ go "ascending" with $a^{-1}$ from $a^{-1}(1- s \lVert a \rVert)$ to $a^{-1}(1)$, the latter being the same as going "descending" with $a$ from $a(s \lVert a \rVert) = a^{-1}(1- s \lVert a \rVert)$ to $a(0) = a^{-1}(1)$.